# Which schemes include pdfLatex

Tags: pdftex, texlive, pandoc

I want to install pdfLatex to use with Pandoc. I know this is included with Tex Live and MikeTex. I am trying to install Tex Live and I would like to select a scheme which is smaller than the full scheme. Which ones include pdfLatex?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While the small (or even basic) scheme should contain pdflatex, the question is which packages you will use, because they might not be in a small scheme.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: I am working on Windows right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing texlive you can choose between these installations:

```
Select scheme:
===============================================================================
 a [X] full scheme (everything)
 b [ ] medium scheme (small + more packages and languages)
 c [ ] small scheme (basic + xetex, metapost, a few languages)
 d [ ] basic scheme (plain and latex)
```

All of them should include the enginge pdfLaTeX, I'd be very surprised, if even basic only had LaTeX.

However, for years I've been installing a customized version: I don't need many languages (english, german and french), but I like having all packages, because you never know.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you give an answer from a minimal point of view? Of course if you're fine to go with 7.7 GB then full is good but do know what to select "at least", please?

Comment: @Semo Sorry, I've no idea, because where I live disk space is really cheap, compared to cost of living, e.g. Maybe start with a minimal installation and then add by trial and error, what's missing for you.

Comment: Yeah, understood, but my aim is about smaller container images without a mass of unused files expanding the image extraordinarily. Perhaps you can give me **?

Comment: @Semo Ask a new question and describe what you want to do and the purpose of the container, maybe someone can help you.